# rolling Hurst exponent

Tags: r, time-series

I am pretty new to R and I have been trying to compute a rolling Hurst exponent with no avail.  I have installed packages fArma (for the Hurst) and zoo (for the rollapply).  The data is in a dataframe called 'data' and is variable 'returns'.  The following code for the Hurst works great;

```
rsFit(data$returns, levels = 50, minnpts = 3, cut.off = 10^c(0.7, 2.5), + doplot = FALSE, trace = FALSE, title = NULL, description = NULL)
```

Below is my attempt at a rolling Hurst exponent of window size 230, which generates an error.

```
rollapply(data$returns, 230, (rsFit(data$returns, levels = 50, minnpts = 3, cut.off = 10^c(0.7, 2.5), + doplot = FALSE, trace = FALSE, title = NULL, description = NULL)))
```

Any help with the code would be much appreciated.  I am trying to calculate the Hurst exponent over a 230 period window, that rolls forward 1 period at a time.

The data is;

```
    returns 
1   -0.002002003    
2   -0.002006019    
3   0.000000000 
4   0.000000000 
5   -0.009077218    
6   -0.003044142    
7   -0.002034589    
8   0.004065046 
9   0.002026343 
10  0.001011634 
11  0.001010612 
12  0.000000000     
13  -0.001010612    
14  -0.001011634    
15  0.003031837 
16  -0.001009591    
17  0.001009591 
18  -0.002020203
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data so that [your example is reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have had another go at it and saved the RS Hurst from fArma as a function called 'HURSTRS'.  I have then applied;

    rollinghurst <- rollapply(x, 230, HURSTRS, by=230, align="right")

But I still get errors.  Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @aur I have provided a lot of matlab codes here: http://prorum.com/index.php/2173/calcular-expoente-dependencia-dependence-series-temporais

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really not familiar with the `fArma` package or its functions, but I noticed a couple of major issues with your code.

1. You are trying to use `rollapply` incorrectly; specifically your third argument `FUN=rsFun(data$returns)`. In general, if you are applying a (one-parameter) function `foo` on a data object `x` with `rollapply`, your function call should be `rollapply(x,some_integer,foo)`.

So in your case, you would have

```
rollapply(data$returns,230,rsFit)
```

since it is acceptable to call `rsFit` with only one argument (the first one, `x`, as shown in the help file `?rsFit`).

2. The `width` of 230 that you are specifying in `rollapply` is much too large - your sample data, `data$returns`, only has a length of 18 - the window size has to be less than the length of the data. One option is to use a smaller `width`: I tried a couple of small values (5,10,...) with your data, but this produced errors. Like I said, I'm not familiar with the functions in `fArma`, but I suspect `rsFit` requires more than 5 or 10 observations at a time. A better solution would be to use a larger sample of data, which is shown below.
3. Even having made the changes described above, you will encounter one more issue. From the **Value** section (i.e. return value) in `?rollapply`:

   > "A object of the same class as data with the results of the rolling
   >   function."

   Typically this is some type of simple object, e.g. a `vector`, `matrix`, etc... depending on your input. However, `rsFit` returns an `S4` class `fHURST` object, which `rollapply` is apparently not able to deal with. This is not surprising, since `fHURST` objects have a fairly complex structure - try running `str(rsFit(data$returns))` and note all of the various slots it contains. Basically, the simple solution for this is instead of returning the entire `fHURST` object calculated in `rollapply`, just return the component / slot that you need. Again, I've never used `rsFit` and I don't have to time to read into the theoretical underpinnings of Hurst exponents, but below I assumed you were mainly concerned with the estimated coefficient values occupying the `@hurst` slot of the `fHURST` objects.

As noted above, I made a toy data set that is much larger than 18 observations so that I could keep the `width=230` in `rollapply`.

```
library(fArma)
library(zoo)
##
set.seed(123)
data2 <- rnorm(690)
##
data2.ra <- rollapply(data2,230,function(x){
  hSlot <- rsFit(x)@hurst
  result <- data.frame(
    H = hSlot$H,
    beta = hSlot$beta,
    Estimate.intercept = hSlot$diag[1,1],
    Estimate.X = hSlot$diag[2,1])
  result
})
##
> head(data2.ra)
          H      beta Estimate.intercept Estimate.X
1 0.6257476 0.6257476       -0.143363281  0.6257476
2 0.6627804 0.6627804       -0.193806373  0.6627804
3 0.6235309 0.6235309       -0.133828565  0.6235309
4 0.5683417 0.5683417       -0.055960572  0.5683417
5 0.5520769 0.5520769       -0.027270395  0.5520769
6 0.5334170 0.5334170       -0.003523383  0.5334170
> dim(data2.ra)
[1] 461   4
> 690 - (230-1)
[1] 461
```

Which is an object of length 461, since the output of using `rollapply` with a window size `k` on an object of length `n` is `n - (k-1)`. Of course, you can change the body of the anonymous function (`function(x){...}`) used in `rollapply` above to suit your needs.